# Joomla blank screen after moving servers

Tags: joomla

I moved a Joomla installation from one server to another. Copied the database and all files. When I moved it into place it all loaded, everything worked fine and after a period of time (like 20 minutes) it now just loads a blank page.

I've traced through the Joomla framework, if I put an echo in before the call to `$app->render()` it works fine and outputs, but the call to `$app->render()` never enters. I.e. I put an echo statement at the top of render() and it was not output. Very bizare, no errors, no output.

Any ideas? Joomla 1.7.3.

EDIT: I just timed it, it worked up until 30 minutes exactly. At this point I get two lines in PHP error_log -

```
[22-Mar-2012 01:35:46 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/off/public_html/components/com_k2/router.php on line 114
[22-Mar-2012 01:35:46 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: text in /home/off/public_html/templates/gk_boutique/error.php on line 27
```

Comment: Did you try using another template ?

Comment: if possible then add your site url

Comment: @sam_13 if you mean the URL to the site as it's running, it's on an internal server so unfortunately it's not possible.

Comment: Have you checked your server log?

Comment: @BobbyJack there is nothing in the Joomla or Apache log.

Comment: @BobbyJack although I did find something in the PHP error_log, which I have amended.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in to the .htaccess

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

The problem is that there is a (sometimes) invisible index.html on the server. There isn't actually a problem causing the blank page, it is just that a blank page. To prove this is whats wrong trying typing in

www.yourdomain.com/index.php

The page should then appear.

*Note don't just delete that .html file, it has its reasons (security), add that to the .htaccess and it should automatically go forward to the index page when you type in www.yourdomain.com*

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. We fixed it by rebuilding PHP of all things, so unfortunately I can't test what you're suggesting.

Comment: I had this same problem. Tried your solution and still showing a blank page. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can login in administrator (yourdomain.com/administrator), try to clear all the cache. The cache was preserved during the migration.